# Java Servlet Returns Status Code 500 With Bad Cookie Domain?

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

Disclaimer: I'm not a Java guy, but ended up having to maintain some Java code.

I was recently trying to debug why a Java server was returning status code 500 on certain requests.  I narrowed it down to some code that essentially did:

```
httpServletResponse.addHeader("Set-Cookie", "FOO=BAR; domain=localhost")
```

If if replaced `domain=localhost` with the domain from the URL, it worked.  If I just removed that line of code, it also worked.

I found this rather surprising.  I'd expect the browser to ignore such a cookie line, or at the least not have the whole server blow up.  Searching around, I couldn't find any documentation about any such constraints.  Is this expected/documented behavior somewhere?

Comment: Please note that it was not the browser who set the cookie, but the server itself. In other words, it's a **bug** in the server's code! You should not think that it was the browser to blow up the server. The server just reacted on the programmer's error by a HTTP 500 error (did you read the exception/stacktrace anyway?). If it were the browser's fault, it would have been a HTTP 4nn error.

Comment: optionally, you may set cookie using [this method](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie%28javax.servlet.http.Cookie%29)

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that its the server sending the Set-Cookie header; I know the browser isn't causing the server to blow up and that its a programmer bug.  There was no stacktrace or logging, just a 500 error, hence the SO question :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enough digging and logging, I eventually tracked this down to the specific servlet server implementation I'm using, which really doesn't like domain=localhost.

What I was really after was some specification that said something like, "Set-cookie with a bad domain value should result in a 500 server error", or otherwise directly addressed the problem of "what servlets should do if a bad cookie domain is given in Set-Cookie."

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path

The last line in that site syas:

> Cookies can be set on only top domain and its sub domains. Setting
>   cookies on www.foo.com from www.bar.com will not work for security
>   reasons.